# excel vba ,to insert a new column to the length of the column next to it and type Ck DUP in column c and fill column B

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried to insert an new column and then insert a value ck dup and use fill down to fill in the column.The number of rows should be equal to the number of rows in Previous column.

Here is the code that i tried with

```
Sub InsertColumn()
        Columns("C:C").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "(Ck Dup)"
        Range("C2").Value = "ck dup"
        Range.FillDown
sub End
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8qJS.png)

Thanks For the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below:

```
Sub InsertColumn()
Dim lLastRow As Long
    lLastRow = Range("B" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Columns("C:C").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    If lLastRow < 2 Then
        MsgBox "Last Row is less then 2. Nothing to fill"
    Else
        Range("C2:C" & lLastRow) = "ck dup"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks For the response i tried the solution its just inserting an new row but not entering the value and filling down.

Comment: it works when you have any data in column C below row two

Comment: fill down works like ctrl+D. When the range on which you call this method is a single cell it copies from a cell above it. When it's a multicell range it copies the values from the cell on the top to all cells below. I'll edit my answer to handle the special cases when `lLastRow` is 0, 1 or 2

Comment: I have added an picture to the post that gives you few more info , The code is working but its not filling up the entire column @user3087386

Comment: imgur is blocked site in my company, but have a look at the update. It should work fine now. If it doesn't I'll have a look when I'm home.

Comment: ok, I saw the picture. I thought originally you have your data in column C, but I understand it's in B, so I just changed C to B in the definition of lLastRow